# On outlook.com, how do I remove "Focused" and "Other" see all emails?

Tags: outlook.com

"Focused" and "Unread" don't assist me, as they don't show all emails.  I'm asking about outlook.com, not the software Microsoft Outlook.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Settings` (Gear icon on top right) and turn off `Focused Inbox`.